# Understanding iterator.next functioning

Tags: java, collections

```
Iterator<String> ir = arr.iterator();

while(ir.hasNext()) { 
    String an = ir.next();
    System.out.println(an);
}
```

In `ArrayList` ir returns a list object pointing to first.
Now `ir.next()` must point to next object.
So why it is pointing to the first object when run first time in loop?

Additionally,

```
ListIterator<String> ir= arr.listIterator();

while(ir.hasNext())
{ 
    String an= ir.next();

    ir.set(an + '+');

    System.out.println(an);
}
```

Why its not appending the `'+'` ?. It just prints the original `ArrayList`.

Comment: Because it starts off *before* the first object; you must call `next` in order to get the first object.

Comment: it returns the value/object first and points to next item. Its like x++ rather than ++x

Comment: Reading the javadoc is a good place to start... it probably would have taken you 1/4 of the time of asking the question.

Answer (score 6):

`hasNext()` merely tells you *if* there is another element in the collection that you can iterate over. `next()` actually returns said element. The initial position of the cursor is *before* the first element.

For example, assume you had the following:

```
  0   1   2   3   4
| 8 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 7 |
```

The cursor is actually pointing to a location *before* the first element:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
  | 8 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 7 |

^
|
cursor
```

When you do `hasNext()`, it checks to see if there is anything at location `cursor + 1`. If you have an empty list, there is nothing at `cursor + 1` (i.e., nothing at index `0`), so it will return false. If you are at the very last element, `cursor + 1 == list.size()` which means there is nothing after the end of the list. If you are anywhere else in the list, `cursor + 1` is a valid index that is populated, so it will return `true`.

When you *actually* do `next()`, it will advance the cursor and return the element at the new position. Now, the cursor is in a new location where it is before the *next* element.

Now it really doesn't even matter how it is being done internally. The cursor *could* be pointing to the very first element the first time. If that is the case, all you would need is special logic to handle that scenario (perhaps a flag that checks to see if `next()` has ever been called).

All you need to understand in the case of an `Iterator` is that `hasNext()` will tell you if there is an element remaining that you can iterate over, and `next()` will return that element. This behavior is consistent across invocations and *should be* consistent across all implementations.

Comment: But accordingly the code
String an= ir.next();

ir.set(an + '+');

System.out.println(an);

must print arraylist with '+' appended to it but its not.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to  mention .Listiterator<String> ir= new listiterator<String>(); Here ir is list iterator . which can modify the current collection element .

Comment: @hitesh. Read the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#set\(E\)). `set(E e)` replaces the *last* element returned by `.next()` with the specified element. You have already called `next()` (before calling `set(E e)`) and stored that in `an`, so it will not change .

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem that the `Iterator` is pointing to the first item before it's called for the first time.

What happens in `next` is the following:

1. Store the current value to be returned later.
2. Advance index to the next value beyond the current value (or "nothing" if off the end of the list).
3. Return the current value from step 1.

It really is pointing to the "next" value at all times, even if the iteration is done and there are no more items, in which case there is no "next" item.

Here's [example source code from `ArrayList`'s iterator](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java), an inner class called `Itr`:

```
private class Itr implements Iterator<E>
    int cursor;       // index of next element to return
```

The default value is `0`, which already points to the first element.

The `next()` method performs the steps above (plus some other steps to prevent modification during iteration).

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public E next() {
   checkForComodification();
   int i = cursor;
   if (i >= size)
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
   Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
   if (i >= elementData.length)
      throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
   cursor = i + 1;
   return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
}
```